# Does anyone know how to run the script in the .json file automatically everytime I open my index.html page?

Tags: javascript, json, npm

There's a **script** section in the .json file and everytime if I want to run my html page( on server ), I need to do it manually by typing `npm run (the script's name)` in the terminal. I'm wondering how I'm gonna be able to run it automatically just by opening my index.html.

Comment: I was trying to say "everytime I open my index.html page?"

Comment: Why don't you move the script part to your index.html and link to the json file from the HTML before? That way, the JSON is accessible to the script part and it's executed when you open index.html

Comment: Why do you want to run a server-side script every time you access an HTML page? Can you rephrase your question in terms of your ultimate goal? Can you provide context as to what "the .json file" is and why running `npm run …` is not an acceptable path forward?

Answer (score 0):

The script is designed to be run from the command line.

If you want to change it so it runs in response to a webpage being loaded:

1. Create a web server (e.g. using Express.js)
2. Rewrite the script so it can be called as a function, then call it when the route for your homepage is accessed

e.g.

```
const yourscript = require("./yourscript.js");

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    yourscript();
    res.render('index')
})
```

(Not an exhaustive example, do read the Express.js documentation)

And make sure you load the webpage by requesting it from the webserver (e.g. `http://localhost:3000/` and not accessing the file from the filesystem directly).

Comment: Hey, thank you for the response, I'll try it to implement this.        :)